# Wget Japanese Characters

Tags: utf-8, wget

I'd like to download urls that contain Japanese characters

```
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B6%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A2%E3%83%95
```

When using wget to download the file, the file name becomes gibberish.

In wget's manual, there is something about the problem:

`If you specify ‘nocontrol’, then the escaping of the control characters is also switched   off. This option may make sense when you are downloading URLs whose names contain UTF-8 characters, on a system which can save and display filenames in UTF-8 (some possible byte values used in UTF-8 byte sequences fall in the range of values designated by Wget as “controls”).`

so I tried to write this. However, it didn't work. What is the problem?

```
wget --restrict-file-names=nocontrol http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B6%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A2%E3%83%95
```

Comment: Is it `nocontrol` or `noncontrol` ?

Comment: I've just tried that command and had no issues. File with name アイザック・アシモフ successfully created. I'm guessing it's either an OS, filesystem, shell or terminal-related problem. Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Japanese language support installed, bash shell, Gnome terminal.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am using Windows 7. But the downloaded file name is 繧｢繧､繧ｶ繝・け繝ｻ繧｢繧ｷ繝｢繝. I have changed my system's encoding to Japanese, but the problem still can't be solved

Comment: Looks like you're plagued by this issue: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?37564 No solution/workaround provided for Windows users, other than installing Linux :-)